# Add caption to CSS fling-minislide

Tags: html, css

I found this very [simple CSS slider](https://www.hyde-design.co.uk/joomla-bites/80-create-a-css-slideshow-no-javascript-required) on the web. Is there a way to add a different caption to each image?

```css
.fling-minislide {width:300px; height:300px; overflow:hidden; position:relative; }
.fling-minislide img{ position:absolute; animation:fling-minislide 20s infinite; opacity:0; width: 100%; height: auto;}

@keyframes fling-minislide {25%{opacity:1;} 40%{opacity:0;}} 
.fling-minislide img:nth-child(4){animation-delay:0s;}
.fling-minislide img:nth-child(3){animation-delay:5s;}
.fling-minislide img:nth-child(2){animation-delay:10s;}
.fling-minislide img:nth-child(1){animation-delay:15s;}
```

```html
<div class="fling-minislide">
  <img src="https://images.icanvas.com/list-square/abstract-photography-1.jpg" alt="Slide 4" />
  <img src="https://images.icanvas.com/list-square/abstract-photography-2.jpg" />

  <img src="https://images.icanvas.com/list-square/abstract-landscapes.jpg" alt="Slide 2" />

  <img src="https://images.icanvas.com/list-square/abstract-expressive.jpg" alt="Slide 1" />
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself preferably in a Stack Snippet. See How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: The snippet is in the original question

Comment: @Daniel i just made an edit with a working demo, have fun.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be to wrap your images in a `<figure>` and then use `<figcaption>` to wrap the text.

Found this example by Googling "image slider caption": https://codepen.io/dudleystorey/pen/kFoGw

Just make sure to change your CSS to target properly through inheritance.

---

I made [this working sample on CodePen](https://codepen.io/JGallardo/pen/YLVmbQ)

Some things to keep in mind:
 * Modify the height of your main container, in this case `.fling-minislide` to allow room for the caption. Otherwise if you want it to appear over the image, you have to modify the `z-index` and position of the wrapper, figure, and the caption.
 * Modify your css inheritance to target the wrapper around the image, in your case `.fling-minislide figure` instead of `.fling-minislide img`
 * Modify the inheritance for the animation to target the wrapper, in this case `.fling-minislide figure:nth-child(4)`
 * Add desired position and height to the caption, in my example I did this

```
figcaption {
    height: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 300px; /* height of the image */
    left:0; 
}
```

Notice that the position was decided based on the height of the image.

I also restricted the height of the image so that they could all display in the same position.

```
figure img {
    height: 300px;
    overflow: hidden;
    Width: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the animation is applied to the `img` and the `img` tag doesn't support a closing tag, Wrap the whole this in a div and add a text after the img can p/span etc... then apply the animation to the divs.

```css
.fling-minislide {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

.fling-minislide div {
    animation: fling-minislide 20s infinite;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
     width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
}
.fling-minislide div p{
    position: absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left:25%;
    font-weight:900;
    font-size:3rem;
}
.fling-minislide img {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
     height: auto;
}


@keyframes fling-minislide {
    25% {
        opacity: 1;
    }

    40% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
}

.fling-minislide div:nth-child(4) {
    animation-delay: 0s;
}

.fling-minislide div:nth-child(3) {
    animation-delay: 5s;
}

.fling-minislide div:nth-child(2) {
    animation-delay: 10s;
}

.fling-minislide div:nth-child(1) {
    animation-delay: 15s;
}
```

```html
<div class="fling-minislide">
 <div>
    <img src="https://images.icanvas.com/list-square/abstract-photography-1.jpg" alt="Slide 4" />
    <p>text1</p>
 </div>
 <div>
   <img src="https://images.icanvas.com/list-square/abstract-photography-2.jpg" /><p>text2</p>
 </div>
 <div>
   <img src="https://images.icanvas.com/list-square/abstract-landscapes.jpg" alt="Slide 2" /><p>text3</p>
 </div>
 <div>
   <img src="https://images.icanvas.com/list-square/abstract-expressive.jpg" alt="Slide 1" /><p>text4</p>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Good explanation, i will use the <figure> and <figcaption> way.

Comment: Whatever suits you :)